# contains and exact pattern matching using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataset like below:

```
campaign_name
abcloancde
abcsolcdf
abcemicdef
emic_estore
Personalloa-nemic_sol
personalloa_nemic
abc/emic-dg-upi:bol
```

where `campaign_name` is the column name. I have another `dictionary` like below:

[image]

According to my use case, I have to sort the dictionary on the basis of the length of `terms` in descending order and have to map it with the `campaign_name` column. Whichever `terms` are **FOUND FIRST** in `campaign_name`, its associated `product_category` and `product` should be picked up. For this, I wrote the below code and it works fine:

```
#Dataset loaded below
initialData = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("file://..../sample_data.csv")
initialData.show()
#Dictionary loaded below
df = spark.read.option("header", 
"true").csv("file://..../mapper.csv")

df_contains = df.filter(df.function == 'contains').drop("function")
df_contains = df_contains.orderBy(length(col("terms")).desc())
w = Window.partitionBy(lit('A')).orderBy(length(col("terms")).desc())
df_contains = df_contains.withColumn("rw", row_number().over(w))


df3 = df_contains.na.fill("").groupBy(lit(1)).agg(collect_list(
    concat(col("rw"), lit(":"), col("terms"), lit(":"), col("product_category"), lit(":"), col("product"))).alias(
    "Check")).withColumn("Check", concat_ws(",", col("Check"))).drop("1")


def categoryFunction(name, Check):
    # checkList = Check.lower().split(",")
    out = ""
    match = False
    for Key in Check.lower().split(","):
        keyword = Key.split(":", 2)
        terms = keyword[1]
        tempOut = keyword[2]
        if terms in name.lower():
            out = tempOut
            match = True
        if match:
            break
    return out


def categoryFunction1(name, Check):
    # checkList = Check.lower().split(",")
    out = ""
    match = False
    for Key in Check.lower().split(","):
        keyword = Key.split(":", 2)
        terms = keyword[1]
        tempOut = keyword[2]
        if terms == name.lower():
            out = tempOut
            match = True
        if match:
            break
    return out


categoryUDF = udf(categoryFunction, StringType())
categoryUDF1 = udf(categoryFunction1, StringType())

df4 = initialData.crossJoin(df3)

finalDF = df4.withColumn("out", categoryUDF(col("campaign_name"), col("Check"))).drop("Check").withColumn("out", split(
    col("out"), ":")).withColumn("product_category", col("out")[0]).withColumn("product", col("out")[1]).drop(
    "out").withColumn("prod", when(col("product").isNull(), "other").otherwise(col("product"))).withColumn("prod_cat",
                                                                                                           when(
                                                                                                               col("product_category") == "",
                                                                                                               "other").otherwise(
                                                                                                               col("product_category"))).drop(
    "product", "product_category")
```

It gives me the below correct output:

```
+---------------------+-----+--------+
|campaign_name        |prod |prod_cat|
+---------------------+-----+--------+
|abcloancde           |     |lending |
|abcsolcdf            |sol  |lending |
|abcemicdef           |other|other   |
|emic_estore          |other|other   |
|personalloan-emic_sol|     |lending |
|personalloan_emic    |     |lending |
|abc/emic-dg-upi:bol  |other|other   |
+---------------------+-----+--------+
```

Now, I want to only pick the `campaign_names` where `prod` and `prod_cat` values are `other`. After getting such `campaign_names` I have to split the `campaign_names` on the basis of `"_"` and again run the condition against the `dictionary` where `function="match"` and pick the `product` and `product_category` as done for `contains`

I have written a `categoryFunction1` UDF for this and it actually works when I am filtering out the required dataset for the `match` condition and doing whatever I need to do and then doing union with the above output(which updates the values for `"other"`).

Is there any way like by using `"case...when..then"` which `explodes` the data as I need and doing the `crossJoin` and then picking up the **FIRST EXACT MATCH** value? Because I am dealing with billions of records so wanted to think of a more optimal solution.

Final `expected` output(contains + exact):

```
+---------------------+-----+--------+
|campaign_name        |prod |prod_cat|
+---------------------+-----+--------+
|abcloancde           |     |lending |
|abcsolcdf            |sol  |lending |
|abcemicdef           |other|other   |
|emic_estore          |emic |cards   |
|personalloan-emic_sol|     |lending |
|personalloan_emic    |     |lending |
|abc/emic-dg-upi:bol  |other|other   |
+---------------------+-----+--------+
```

**`Catch`**:
There is one scenario that I missed in the question. I have to eliminate all the delimiters while comparing for contains and for the exact match I can consider all the delimiters but just have to split the words on the basis of `"_"` and then compare them.

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: You'd better provide a better (and complete) sample input, expected output as text, not image. You've done a pretty good job on describing your problem, but I'm still haveing some trouble reproducing your code

Comment: I have updated the question as suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UDFs can be expensive on a spark cluster when compared to using the spark api which can take advantage of spark optimizations. I understand why you created `df3` to include in your udfs, however this may not be necessary. Especially when the size of your dictionary data may grow and the aggregations to create `df3` can be expensive and result in data spills (from memory to disk) since you are grouping everything in 1 row. If it is considerably smaller than the campaign data you may opt to `broadcast` the dataframe with the dictionary data.

Based on your sample data `df_contains` has the following

```py
df_contains = dictionaryDf.filter(dictionaryDf.function == 'contains').drop("function").na.fill("")
df_contains.show(truncate=False)
```

```
+-----+----------------+-------+
|terms|product_category|product|
+-----+----------------+-------+
|loan |Lending         |       |
|sol  |Lending         |SOL    |
+-----+----------------+-------+
```

Another approach using only the spark api is to:

## Approach 1

### Part 1

*NB. You've already achieved part 1 using your UDFs*

1. Left join the dictionary data (broadcast if this improves your performance) on whether the term is located in the campaign name.
2. You may then use the window function row number to identify the longest term first or as you have described it :

> I have to sort the dictionary on the basis of the length of terms in descending order and have to map it with the campaign_name column

3. Select your desired columns and use your case expression logic (i.e. with when)

The approach may be coded as below:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

output_df = (
    # Step 1
    initial_data.join(
                    F.broadcast(df_contains),
                    F.col("campaign_name").contains(F.col("terms")),
                    "left"
                )
    # Step 2
                .withColumn(
                    "rn",
                    F.row_number().over(
                        Window.partitionBy("campaign_name")
                              .orderBy(
                                  F.length(F.col("terms")).desc()
                              )
                    )
                )
                .filter("rn=1")
    # Step 3
                .select(
                    "campaign_name",
                    F.when(
                        F.col("product").isNull(),"other"
                    ).otherwise(F.col("product")).alias("prod"),
                    F.when(
                        F.col("product_category").isNull(),"other"
                    ).otherwise(F.col("product_category")).alias("prod_cat")
                )
)
output_df.show(truncate=False)
```

which results in the following output (*NB. ordering of rows in spark is non-deterministic unless an order is specified*) :

```
+---------------------+-----+--------+
|campaign_name        |prod |prod_cat|
+---------------------+-----+--------+
|abc/emic-dg-upi:bol  |other|other   |
|abcemicdef           |other|other   |
|abcloancde           |     |Lending |
|abcsolcdf            |SOL  |Lending |
|emic_estore          |other|other   |
|personalloan-emic_sol|     |Lending |
|personalloan_emic    |     |Lending |
+---------------------+-----+--------+
```

### Part 2

We may solve the remainder of your problem with a similar approach as above

1. Split the `campaign_name` by `_` and use `explode` to get multiple rows for each piece
2. Left Join on the split campaign name, aliased below as  `cname_split`, and where `prod` and `prod_cat` are equal to `other` for the split campaign names
3. Instead of using a when/case expression to check for null matches and re-assign the original value we may use `coalesce` which assigns the first non-null value
4. Since we have multiple rows for each `campaign_name` after the explode, we may aggregate, however in the example below, I've used `row_number` to filter the duplicate entries and order by available `product` names.

NB. `df_match` as referenced below was retrieved using

```py
df_match = dictionaryDf.filter(dictionaryDf.function == 'match').drop("function").na.fill("")
df_match.show(truncate=False)
```

```
+------------+----------------+-------+
|terms       |product_category|product|
+------------+----------------+-------+
|personalloan|Lending         |UL     |
|emic        |Cards           |EMIC   |
+------------+----------------+-------+
```

Code:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

output_df2 = (
    # Step 1
    output_df.select(
                 "*",
                 F.explode(F.split("campaign_name","_")).alias("cname_split")
             )
    # Step 2
             .join(
                 df_match,
                 (
                     F.col("campaign_name").contains("_") &
                     F.col("cname_split").contains(F.col("terms")) &
                     (F.col("prod") == "other") &
                     (F.col("prod_cat") == "other")
                 ),
                 "left"
             )
    # Step 3
             .select(
                 "campaign_name",
                 F.coalesce("product","prod").alias("prod"),
                 F.coalesce("product_category","prod_cat").alias("prod_cat"),
    # Step 4
                 F.row_number().over(
                     Window.partitionBy("campaign_name")
                           .orderBy(
                               F.col("product").isNull()
                           )
                 ).alias("rn")
             )
             .filter("rn=1")
             .drop("rn")
)

output_df2.show(truncate=False)
```

```
+---------------------+-----+--------+
|campaign_name        |prod |prod_cat|
+---------------------+-----+--------+
|abc/emic-dg-upi:bol  |other|other   |
|abcemicdef           |other|other   |
|abcloancde           |     |Lending |
|abcsolcdf            |SOL  |Lending |
|emic_estore          |EMIC |Cards   |
|personalloan-emic_sol|     |Lending |
|personalloan_emic    |     |Lending |
+---------------------+-----+--------+
```

## Approach 2

This is similar to the approach above however, it is more optimal as it achieves it's aim using less joins.

Code:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

output_df3 = (
    initial_data.withColumn("cname_split",F.explode(F.split("campaign_name","_")))
                .join(
                    dictionaryDf,
                    (
                        (
                            (F.col("function")=="contains") &
                            F.col("campaign_name").contains(F.col("terms")) 
                        ) | 
                        (
                           (F.col("function")=="match") &
                           F.col("campaign_name").contains("_") &
                           F.col("cname_split").contains(F.col("terms")) 
                           
                        )
                    ),
                    "left"
                )
                .withColumn(
                    "empty_is_other",
                    F.when(
                        (
                            F.col("product").isNull() & 
                            F.col("product_category").isNull()
                        ),
                        "other"
                    )
                )
                .withColumn(
                    "rn",
                    F.row_number().over(
                        Window.partitionBy("campaign_name")
                              .orderBy(
                                  F.when(
                                      F.col("function").isNull(),3
                                  ).when(
                                      F.col("function")=="match",2
                                  ).otherwise(1),
                                  F.length(F.col("terms")).desc(),
                                  F.col("product").isNull()
                              )
                    )
                )
                .filter("rn=1")
                .select(
                    "campaign_name",
                    F.coalesce("product","empty_is_other").alias("prod"),
                    F.coalesce("product_category","empty_is_other").alias("prod_cat"),
                )
                .na.fill("")
)
output_df3.show(truncate=False)
```

Outputs

```
+---------------------+-----+--------+
|campaign_name        |prod |prod_cat|
+---------------------+-----+--------+
|abc/emic-dg-upi:bol  |other|other   |
|abcemicdef           |other|other   |
|abcloancde           |     |Lending |
|abcsolcdf            |SOL  |Lending |
|emic_estore          |EMIC |Cards   |
|personalloan-emic_sol|     |Lending |
|personalloan_emic    |     |Lending |
+---------------------+-----+--------+
```

Output before `.filter("rn=1")` for clarification

```
+---------------------+-------------------+------------+----------------+-------+--------+--------------+---+
|campaign_name        |cname_split        |terms       |product_category|product|function|empty_is_other|rn |
+---------------------+-------------------+------------+----------------+-------+--------+--------------+---+
|abc/emic-dg-upi:bol  |abc/emic-dg-upi:bol|null        |null            |null   |null    |other         |1  |
|abcemicdef           |abcemicdef         |null        |null            |null   |null    |other         |1  |
|abcloancde           |abcloancde         |loan        |Lending         |null   |contains|null          |1  |
|abcsolcdf            |abcsolcdf          |sol         |Lending         |SOL    |contains|null          |1  |
|emic_estore          |emic               |emic        |Cards           |EMIC   |match   |null          |1  |
|emic_estore          |estore             |null        |null            |null   |null    |other         |2  |
|personalloan-emic_sol|personalloan-emic  |loan        |Lending         |null   |contains|null          |1  |
|personalloan-emic_sol|sol                |loan        |Lending         |null   |contains|null          |2  |
|personalloan-emic_sol|personalloan-emic  |sol         |Lending         |SOL    |contains|null          |3  |
|personalloan-emic_sol|sol                |sol         |Lending         |SOL    |contains|null          |4  |
|personalloan-emic_sol|personalloan-emic  |personalloan|Lending         |UL     |match   |null          |5  |
|personalloan-emic_sol|personalloan-emic  |emic        |Cards           |EMIC   |match   |null          |6  |
|personalloan_emic    |personalloan       |loan        |Lending         |null   |contains|null          |1  |
|personalloan_emic    |emic               |loan        |Lending         |null   |contains|null          |2  |
|personalloan_emic    |personalloan       |personalloan|Lending         |UL     |match   |null          |3  |
|personalloan_emic    |emic               |emic        |Cards           |EMIC   |match   |null          |4  |
+---------------------+-------------------+------------+----------------+-------+--------+--------------+---+
```

## Update 1

In response to question update:

> Catch:
>
> There is one scenario that I missed in the question. I have to
> eliminate all the delimiters while comparing for contains and for the
> exact match I can consider all the delimiters but just have to split
> the words on the basis of "_" and then compare them.

`regexp_replace` was used to remove special characters. See update below:

```py
output_df3 = ( # _/:
    initial_data.withColumn("cname_split",F.explode(F.split("campaign_name","_")))
                .withColumn(
                    "campaign_name_clean",
                    F.regexp_replace(
                        F.lower(F.col("campaign_name")),
                        '[^a-zA-Z0-9]',
                        ""
                    )
                )
                .join(
                    dictionaryDf,
                    (
                        (
                            (F.col("function")=="contains") &
                            F.col("campaign_name_clean").contains(F.col("terms")) 
                        ) | 
                        (
                           (F.col("function")=="match") &
                           F.col("campaign_name").contains("_") &
                           (F.col("cname_split")==F.col("terms"))
                           
                        )
                    ),
                    "left"
                )
                .withColumn(
                    "empty_is_other",
                    F.when(
                        (
                            (
                                (F.col("function")=="contains") | F.col("function").isNull()
                            ) &
                            F.col("product").isNull() & 
                            F.col("product_category").isNull()
                        ),
                        "other"
                    )
                )
                .withColumn(
                    "rn",
                    F.row_number().over(
                        Window.partitionBy("campaign_name")
                              .orderBy(
                                  F.when(
                                      F.col("function").isNull(),3
                                  ).when(
                                      F.col("function")=="match",2
                                  ).otherwise(1),
                                  F.length(F.col("terms")).desc(),
                                  F.col("product").isNull()
                              )
                    )
                )
                .filter("rn=1")
                .select(
                    "campaign_name",
                    F.coalesce("product","empty_is_other").alias("prod"),
                    F.coalesce("product_category","empty_is_other").alias("prod_cat"),
                )
                .na.fill("")
)
output_df3.show(truncate=False)
```

Outputs:

```
+---------------------+-----+--------+
|campaign_name        |prod |prod_cat|
+---------------------+-----+--------+
|Personalloa-nemic_sol|     |Lending |
|abc/emic-dg-upi:bol  |other|other   |
|abcemicdef           |other|other   |
|abcloancde           |     |Lending |
|abcsolcdf            |SOL  |Lending |
|emic_estore          |EMIC |Cards   |
|personalloa_nemic    |     |Lending |
+---------------------+-----+--------+
```

Output before `.filter("rn=1")` for debugging purposes

```
+---------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----+----------------+-------+--------+--------------+---+
|campaign_name        |cname_split        |campaign_name_clean|terms|product_category|product|function|empty_is_other|rn |
+---------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----+----------------+-------+--------+--------------+---+
|Personalloa-nemic_sol|Personalloa-nemic  |personalloanemicsol|loan |Lending         |null   |contains|null          |1  |
|Personalloa-nemic_sol|sol                |personalloanemicsol|loan |Lending         |null   |contains|null          |2  |
|Personalloa-nemic_sol|Personalloa-nemic  |personalloanemicsol|sol  |Lending         |SOL    |contains|null          |3  |
|Personalloa-nemic_sol|sol                |personalloanemicsol|sol  |Lending         |SOL    |contains|null          |4  |
|abc/emic-dg-upi:bol  |abc/emic-dg-upi:bol|abcemicdgupibol    |null |null            |null   |null    |other         |1  |
|abcemicdef           |abcemicdef         |abcemicdef         |null |null            |null   |null    |other         |1  |
|abcloancde           |abcloancde         |abcloancde         |loan |Lending         |null   |contains|null          |1  |
|abcsolcdf            |abcsolcdf          |abcsolcdf          |sol  |Lending         |SOL    |contains|null          |1  |
|emic_estore          |emic               |emicestore         |emic |Cards           |EMIC   |match   |null          |1  |
|emic_estore          |estore             |emicestore         |null |null            |null   |null    |other         |2  |
|personalloa_nemic    |personalloa        |personalloanemic   |loan |Lending         |null   |contains|null          |1  |
|personalloa_nemic    |nemic              |personalloanemic   |loan |Lending         |null   |contains|null          |2  |
+---------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----+----------------+-------+--------+--------------+---+
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I can see the efforts behind the answer. I have to try it yet but I have updated the catch part in the question. Can I do it using your second approach?

Comment: To make it clear, I have updated the input dataset as well.

Comment: @Debuggerrr What do you mean by " I have to eliminate all the characters while comparing for contains" ? If you eliminate all characters you will have an empty string, are you referring to a particular set of characters?

Comment: Apologies. I meant delimiters like `_/:`. Also, updated the question regarding the same

Comment: I made the changes to your second approach and I am editing your second approach answer. It worked for me but can you review it once? Just to make sure it is the right way of doing it

Comment: @Debuggerrr I've updated the answer with an edit. I used `regexp_replace` to remove non alpha-numeric characters. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: This is perfect 